# Excel 2016 find/match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, find

I'm trying to write a formula that can return an array based on if each value in a range can be found within a set found in another range.

For example, if I have: a range A2:A7 with text values 1,2,3,4,5,6 and a range B2:B4 with text values 2,4,6

I want to use a function like: find(A2:A7,B2:B4)

and get the result: {0;1;0;1;0;1} (when I press f9)

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Imy.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by the following formula:

```
=MMULT(IFERROR(FIND(A1:A6,TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)),0),--NOT(ISBLANK(B1:B3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `D1`, enter formula :

```
=0+ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B3,0))
```

then, highlight `D1` and hit `F9`, the formula bar will return (something like in `E1`) >>

```
={0;1;0;1;0;1}
```

[image]